# Conditaionl Formating of row when field is not displayed

Tags: list-view, formatting, conditional

Seems simple, but I cant figure it out. I want to highlight a row based on text being entered in a field, but the field is NOT displayed. 
It shows up the way I want if the field is showing up in the list, but I don't want it to.

Comment: Please elaborate more to your question. Unable to identify what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I have setup a conditional format on a list. It highlights the row if there is a comment in one of the fields (no highlight is applied if there is no comment). But if I remove the field from the view I have (the field is still available in the all items list)  the highlighting goes away. I want it to still display regardless if the field is in the view or not.